# Python split string at spaces as usual, but keep certain substrings containing space?

Tags: python, parsing, split

Consider I have the following string:

```
>>> aa="63452 [  0] AAA BB CCC"
```

If I do the usual `.split()` which splits at whitespaces, I get this:

```
>>> aa.split()
['63452', '[', '0]', 'AAA', 'BB', 'CCC']
```

What I'd want to obtain instead, is this list: `['63452', '[  0]', 'AAA', 'BB', 'CCC']`

Basically, the second part is a string that matches the format: opening square bracket + none or more of whitespace characters + none or more digits + closing square bracket - which I can match with this regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\[\s*\d*\]', aa)
['[  0]']
```

In essence, I'd first want to identify the "square bracket" item, then split as `.split()` usually does it, while keeping the "square bracket" item.

So, what would be the most straightforward way, to obtain the desired list from the given string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an alternation pattern that matches a bracketed string or non-space characters:

```
re.findall(r'\[.*?]|\S+', aa)
```